# Can the new Office365 APIs be used in SharePoint Apps

Tags: api, office365

seems like the new APIs could be used in SharePoint Apps, but can they?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on the blog http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/

No, these APIs are intended for use in the Mobile Device and Web Application projects. The reason for this is that the Office 365 APIs use Azure AD for authentication through User consent on usage, whereas the for Apps for SharePoint uses OAuth through App consent on deploying them. As of now, Azure AD does not have a construct for Apps to have all User consent, it only has it for Users’ to individually give consent an App. If this is something that is important, we would love to hear this on our UserVoice with specific scenarios of interest http://aka.ms/OfficeDevFeedback